# Bamboo unit test integration error: CORBA connection failure with minor code 4000

Tags: .net, nunit, bamboo, corba

All tests pass when I run locally as connection is established successfully. but when I connect through bamboo, I get the below error.

CORBA system exception : omg.org.CORBA.TRANSIENT [Unable to connect to target.] , completed: Completed_No minor: 4000 What may be the issue? Please help.

Comment: Could be a network setup issue, can you enable any logging to see what is happening?

Comment: Sure Johnny. What type of logging? I have unit test where corba connection has to be established. It fails at that moment. Can I add any log related to network issues?

Comment: Check the documentation of your CORBA implementation, which product are you using, on which platform, which compiler, etc, you provide no details